# Как перевести JavaScript в Python?

Tags: javascript, python

Есть функция encrypt.js, которая используется для вычисления токена для входа в админ-панель роутера. Я пишу python-скрипт, который позволит управлять роутером программно, и мне нужно каким-то образом вычислять этот самый токен.
В самом скрипте около 300 строк, и некоторые операторы типа побитовых сдвигов, если честно, затрудняют мне ручной перевод.
Кто может посоветовать действующий способ или альтернативу к нему?
Вот, собственно, сам 
**encrypt.js:**

```
function hex_md5(s)
{ 
    return binl2hex(core_md5(str2binl(s), s.length * 8));
}

function core_md5(x, len)
{
  /* append padding */
  x[len >> 5] |= 0x80 << ((len) % 32);
  x[(((len + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = len;

  var a =  1732584193;
  var b = -271733879;
  var c = -1732584194;
  var d =  271733878;

  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16)
  {
    var olda = a;
    var oldb = b;
    var oldc = c;
    var oldd = d;

    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 7 , -680876936);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 1], 12, -389564586);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 17,  606105819);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 3], 22, -1044525330);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 7 , -176418897);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 5], 12,  1200080426);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 17, -1473231341);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 7], 22, -45705983);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 7 ,  1770035416);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 9], 12, -1958414417);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 17, -42063);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+11], 22, -1990404162);
    a = md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 7 ,  1804603682);
    d = md5_ff(d, a, b, c, x[i+13], 12, -40341101);
    c = md5_ff(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 17, -1502002290);
    b = md5_ff(b, c, d, a, x[i+15], 22,  1236535329);

    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 5 , -165796510);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 6], 9 , -1069501632);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 14,  643717713);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 0], 20, -373897302);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 5 , -701558691);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+10], 9 ,  38016083);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 14, -660478335);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 4], 20, -405537848);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 5 ,  568446438);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+14], 9 , -1019803690);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 14, -187363961);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 8], 20,  1163531501);
    a = md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 5 , -1444681467);
    d = md5_gg(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 2], 9 , -51403784);
    c = md5_gg(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 14,  1735328473);
    b = md5_gg(b, c, d, a, x[i+12], 20, -1926607734);

    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 5], 4 , -378558);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 8], 11, -2022574463);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+11], 16,  1839030562);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+14], 23, -35309556);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 1], 4 , -1530992060);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 4], 11,  1272893353);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 7], 16, -155497632);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+10], 23, -1094730640);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+13], 4 ,  681279174);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 0], 11, -358537222);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 3], 16, -722521979);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 6], 23,  76029189);
    a = md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 9], 4 , -640364487);
    d = md5_hh(d, a, b, c, x[i+12], 11, -421815835);
    c = md5_hh(c, d, a, b, x[i+15], 16,  530742520);
    b = md5_hh(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 2], 23, -995338651);

    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 0], 6 , -198630844);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 7], 10,  1126891415);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+14], 15, -1416354905);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 5], 21, -57434055);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+12], 6 ,  1700485571);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+ 3], 10, -1894986606);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+10], 15, -1051523);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 1], 21, -2054922799);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 8], 6 ,  1873313359);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+15], 10, -30611744);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 6], 15, -1560198380);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+13], 21,  1309151649);
    a = md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x[i+ 4], 6 , -145523070);
    d = md5_ii(d, a, b, c, x[i+11], 10, -1120210379);
    c = md5_ii(c, d, a, b, x[i+ 2], 15,  718787259);
    b = md5_ii(b, c, d, a, x[i+ 9], 21, -343485551);

    a = safe_add(a, olda);
    b = safe_add(b, oldb);
    c = safe_add(c, oldc);
    d = safe_add(d, oldd);
  }
  return Array(a, b, c, d);

}

function md5_cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t)
{
  return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(a, q), safe_add(x, t)), s),b);
}
function md5_ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}
function md5_ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t)
{
  return md5_cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

/*
 * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally
 * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
 */
function safe_add(x, y)
{
  var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
  var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
  return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}

function bit_rol(num, cnt)
{
  return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
}

function str2binl(str)
{
  var bin = Array();
  var mask = (1 << 8) - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length * 8; i += 8)
    bin[i>>5] |= (str.charCodeAt(i / 8) & mask) << (i%32);
  return bin;
}

function binl2hex(binarray)
{
  var hex_tab = "0123456789abcdef";
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < binarray.length * 4; i++)
  {
    str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
           hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8  )) & 0xF);
  }
  return str;
}

function Base64Encoding(input) 
{
    var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    //input = utf8_encode(input);

    while (i < input.length) 
    {

        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;
}

function utf8_encode (string) 
{
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
    var utftext = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

        if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
        else {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }

    }

    return utftext;
}
```

Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы мы перевели за вас?) Не так уже и много кода - за пару часов точно можно перевести. В чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, понимаю, работы не очень много, но все ли функции из js доступны в пайтоне?

Comment: На 100% не уверен, но думаю, что все. Да и нет ничего особенного в приведенном js коде. Но если вам совсем лениво - можете попробовать https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/. Найдено после 3 минут гугления.